# in datafactory how i will generate TSV files as out put what kind of setting do i need to take

Tags: azure-data-factory

1. source :sql target :BLOB

   output should be  in TSV format

2 : output need to copy to BLOB

Comment: source is BLOB or SQL? Output is a TSV file in BLOB?

Comment: yes my dear source is sql and sink is blob and sholu be in TSV format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a **blob storage dataset** for sink and copy the file as `.TSV`

1. Create a SQL source dataset.
2. Create a Delimited sink dataset and select column delimiter as a tab. Also, create a dataset parameter for the file name.

[image]

3. In Copy data activity, connect SQL source dataset in Source and delimited sink dataset in Sink.

[image]

4. Provide the sink file name with `.TSV`

[image]

**Output file in blob:**

[image]